# JS access grandchild property by string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How would I go about accessing a grandchild property of an object in the following scenario?

I am trying to make a sort function that takes a criteria and sorts by that criteria

```js
const data = [
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 2
    }
  }
},
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1
    }
  }
}
```

```js
sortBy(array, criteria){
  array.sort((a,b) => {
    if (a[criteria] > b[criteria]) return 1;
    ...
  }
}
```

I realize this doesn't quite work but the general idea would be to call `sortyBy(data, "a.b.c")`.

Comment: You would have to split the criteria, and recursively/iteratively dig down to the level it refers to

Comment: That was my first thought, was hoping there might be an easier way, recursion always throws me for a loop... har har... Especially in this scenario

Comment: Doesn't have to be recursion, can be just a loop, but you will have to write it yourself.  There is not a built in way, afaik, to use an json access string path (for lack of a better term) to access nested elements natively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can have the criteria as an array like this.

```
const data = [{
    a: {
      b: {
        c: 2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    a: {
      b: {
        c: 1
      }
    }
  }
]

const sortBy = (array, criteria) => {
  getVal = (val) => {
    return criteria.reduce((a, c) => {
      return a[c];
    }, val);
  };

  array.sort((x, y) => {
    return getVal(x) > getVal(y) ? 1 : -1
  });
};

sortBy(data, ["a", "b", "c"]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
```

Comment: in that case just make that array with `sortBy(data, 'a.b.c'.split('.'))`?

Comment: @gman, that makes sense to me, seems a little more explicit than just and array

Answer (score 0):

If you can use lodash, the function `_.sortBy` does what you need.  The lodash it's a very tested library, so you don't need to reinvent that logic.

```js
let data = [{  a: {    b: {      c: 2    }  }},{  a: {    b: {      c: 1    }  }}],
    sorted = _.sortBy(data, "a.b.c");

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```